# set proportional height based on width

Tags: javascript

assume i have a div with width 320px, what number should i applied to height so it look proportional in landscape?

320px is just an example, the width will be responsive. so i need formula, not a fixed value for height based on that 320px width.

i tried to follow this method:

```
var maxWidth = 550;
var w = dimension.width;
var h = dimension.height;
if(w > maxWidth){
    var ratio = maxWidth / w;
    w *= ratio;
    h *= ratio;
}
```

but i am not sure what value for `h`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is a mathematical problem, not a programming problem

Comment: ok, i see. but i think you need math when you coding a game, programing + math.

Comment: That's true, but it is further not clear what you think the problem with your current code is - it adjusts width and height by the same ratio, retaining the original proportions.

Comment: assuming that the width is 320px, as would be the size (height)?